# Querying geometry in perimeter or square with SpatiaLite?

Tags: sql, spatialite

How can I query geometry in a perimeter or a square with SpatiaLite?

```
CREATE TABLE points (id INTEGER,geom GEOMETRY)
insert into points values (897, GeomFromText('POINT(40.0 3.0)'))
```

I've tried several functions:

```
select id, AsText(geom) from points where PtDistWithin(PointFromText(40.0,3.0),geom, 5000.0);
select id, AsText(geom) from points where ST_Distance(PointFromText(POINT(40.0 3.0)),geom)< 5000.0;
select id, AsText(geom) from points where MBRContains(BuildCircleMBR(40.0,3.0, 5000),geom);
```

None of those return any result, or they don't use meters (they return all or no result when I change the radius) so I have some trouble understanding how to use meters.

Note that I'm not using QGIS or other software, I'm calling SpatiaLite from python but it is only the SQL not Python that I seek help with here.

Comment: Is your aim to store the geometries in lat-long degrees and query them by giving the reference geometry also in degrees, but the distance in meters? That is only partly supported by SpatiaLite. Can you consider using PostGIS instead?

Comment: It is essential to make first SQL queries which give desired results. Of course later the SQL must be executed correctly from Python but right now it is relevant to consentrate on SQL. There are many examples about how to  use GDAL ExecuteSQL in https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/master/autotest/ogr/ogr_sqlite.py.

Comment: @user30184 I'd rather use spatialite, it's more lightweight, even if its feature are lacking.

Comment: Please verify what you mean with "POINT (40.0 3.0)". Is that a point with geographical longitude-latitude coordinates or just dummy point that can be in whatever coordinate system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distance queries by using longitude-latitude coordinates for the geometries and by giving the distance as meters are possible with SpatiaLite by calling ST_Distance with three parameters http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html

> ST_Distance( geom1 Geometry , geom2 Geometry , use_ellipsoid Boolean )
>   : Double precision
>
> return the distance between geom1 and geom2 (measured in meters). If
>   the use_ellipsoid argument is set to TRUE the precise (but slower)
>   distance will be computed on the Ellipsoid, otherwise will be computed
>   on the Great Cicle (approximative, but faster).
>
> This function only supports Long/Lat coordinates, and will return NULL
>   for any planar CRS

I modified your SQL a bit to include explicit EPSG codes for the geometries. They may not be stritcly compulsory always but it is a good habit. Notice also that SpatiaLite is using axis order longitude-latitude for EPSG:4326.

```
CREATE TABLE points (id INTEGER,geom GEOMETRY)
insert into points values (897, GeomFromText('POINT(40.0 3.0)',4326))
```

Test the distance query with two parameters

```
select ST_Distance(GeomFromText('POINT(40.1 3.0)',4326),geom) from points;
Result: 0.1
```

Test the distance query with three parameters, first with the Great Circle distance

```
select ST_Distance(GeomFromText('POINT(40.1 3.0)',4326),geom,0) from points;
Result: 11104.269070
```

Next with the distance along the ellipsoid

```
select ST_Distance(GeomFromText('POINT(40.1 3.0)',4326),geom,1) from points;
Result: 11116.795047
```

Now you can use your second query to test if points (40.0 3.0) and (40.1 3.0) are within 20 kilometers

```
select id, AsText(geom) from points where ST_Distance(GeomFromText('POINT(40.1 3.0)',4326),geom,0)< 20000.0;
```

Function PtDistWithin has even more strict rules for long-lat geometries but it can be used for your test points.

> return TRUE (1) if the distance between geom1 and geom2 is within the
>   given range. Usually distances are expressed in the length unit
>   corresponding to the geoms own SRID: but if both geoms are simple
>   POINTs and their SRID is 4326 (i.e. WGS84), then distances are
>   expressed in meters. In this later case the optional arg use_spheroid
>   can be used to select the distance algorithm to be used: is
>   use_spheroid = 1 the slowest but most accurate geodesic distance will
>   be evaluated: in any other case the simplest great circle distance
>   will be used instead

Query that computes distanse along the spheroid

```
select id, AsText(geom) from points where PtDistWithin(GeomFromText('POINT (40.1 3.0)',4326),geom,20000,1);
```

Comment: `select id, PtDistWithin(Transform(geom, 4326) , GeomFromText('POINT(43.60 3.83)', 4326), %f, 0) from points` doesn't seem to work, results are (897, None) for all... Using ST_Distance works well. Replacing `Transform(geom, 4326)` with `geom` seem to use degrees.

Comment: Correct PtDistWithin query now added.

Comment: I still have an issue to use meters https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47704966#47704966